# Android internal storage is showing less than actual size

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Samsung Galaxy Grand GT-I9082. The phone has 8GB internal storage.

If I go to **Setting → Storage**, I see that

- the total storage is `8 GB` and
- the available storage is `14 MB`.

I have reset my phone (hard reset and wipe), but the available storage hasn't changed! What's the problem?

Comment: Seems like a bug in the stock ROM universal to Samsung phones [Related article](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-grand/328088-my-galaxy-grand-device-memory-shows-used-space-12-29-gb-when-total-device-capacity-8gb.html#post3230923) A user suggested that Software update from samsung service centre solved the problem. Alternatively you can restore [firmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) using ODIN but be sure to take _backup_ prior to both the processes.